# Composer PSR-0 autoloading dont work

Tags: php, composer-php

I have problem with autoloading module controller class from my app. I try to configure composer.json but still not working. Probably am doing somthing wrong with this directory structure. I try examples from composer doc but again dont work...

**Directory structure:**

```
|- admin
|----- modules
|--------- Menu
|------------Controller
|--------------MenuController.php
```

Lets see **composer.json**

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "Admin\\Modules\\": "" }
  }
}
```

I try to set path but nothing again // "Admin\Modules\": "admin/modules"

**Menu controller**:

```
namespace Admin\Modules\Menu\Controller;

class MenuController extends AbstractAdminBaseController
```

**FrontController**

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

new \Admin\Modules\Menu\Controller\MenuController();
```

All time Class not found. I try 100 examples from google and nothing. Any example how to slowe this problem? Thanks

**Update structure:**

```
├───admin
│   └───modules
│         └───Menu
│            └───controller
│                    └───MenuController.php
├───vednor
│   └───autoload.php
│   └───composer
│          └───autoload_classmap.php
│          └───autoload_namespaces.php
│          └───autoload_psr4.php
│          └───autoload_real.php
│          └───ClassLoader.php
├───public
├───assets
├───index.php
├───composer.json
├───composer.lock
```

Comment: As you're using namespaces, perhaps you should be using a [PSR-4](http://seld.be/notes/psr-4-autoloading-support-in-composer) (namespace compliant) autoloader, rather than a PSR-0 autoloader

Comment: After psr-0 i try this with psr-4. With psr-4 i must define all module name like `Menu`, `Product` in composer.

Comment: Can you post the full directory structure? (Full path to composer.json, autoload.php, FrontController.php, MenuController.php)

Comment: Which operating system are you using? If you are using a case sensitive OS, your problem may be caused by the fact that the directory names do not match the case of your namespaces. Try using the exact same case (`Admin` instead of `admin`, `Modules` instead of `modules`, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Your PSR-0 will never work, because this standard dictates that the path to the file has to be EXACTLY like the classname. Note that your first part of the namespace is "Admin", but the first directory part is only "admin" - cases must match exactly, or it won't work (or will only work with case insensitive filesystems).

You will succeed with using PSR-4, though. Why? Because with PSR-4, the given namespace prefix is removed from the full classname, and the rest is being converted into a path that is searched in the directory given for the namespace prefix.

Example for your case:

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-0": { "Admin\\Modules\\": "" }
}
```

Will not work because the files are in path `admin/modules`, but must be in `Admin/Modules`.

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": { "Admin\\Modules\\": "admin/modules/" }
}
```

Will work because the prefix `Admin\Modules\` is removed and the remaining class name is being converted to a path and added to `admin/modules`.

Ah, one gotcha! It will NOT work, because you chose to name the class `...\Controller\...`, but the path once again `.../controller/...`.

Honestly, I'd highly recommend to convert your file names and location to PSR-4 compatibility, even for the prefixed directories that you'd be able to work around with Composer. This will eliminate the surprising lowercase directory structures I see.

I mean: Why is that `controller` directory even lower case in the first place if every class located there is `Controller`? I really can't understand this.